# A bizarre situation with an input field within the form

Tags: javascript, php, encoding, webforms

I am in a rather bizarre situation. There is a registration form which consists of few input fields and only ONE of them (the name of the club field) does not accept special characters. I need it to be able to show š đ ć č (croatian letters). The user is supposed to fill in the form and when hits a submit button, the info is sending to an email address. Data is not written in a database, it is only sent to an email address. When I test the form and put š đ č ć letters in the name of the club field, the form doesn't send at all. If I do not put any of these characters in that field, the form sends ok. All other fields accept these characters with no problem. All files are UTF-8 encoding. 
My form consists of plain html input fields, but I have two files which send email.

Does anyone have a suggestion of some kind, if you ever had this kind of problem?

Thank you.

Comment: What framework, language are you using? Please add a fragment of the code you have.

Comment: Hi Mikhail, I edited the code. It is php and also there is some javascript. Any suggestions? I am totally lost.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't encoding at all. The problem was that I had a $name_of_club variable in a subject of a message and apparently it's a no no.